# Submenu still visible after unfolding and folding it back in SSMS "browse mode."

Tags: ssas, ssms, cube

I have deployed a cube in SSAS and browsing it in SSMS. I have several hierarchies and i unfold these, for example: Product type - Product Subtype - Product.

When i have finished looking at those sub-hierarhies i press "minus-sign" on the top hierarchie and all the lower details dissapears(as it should), but not the headlines, for example the product subtype. Where can i change this when i am making my cube? Or is it something in SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like i have to drag and drop this outside to get rid of it.